# Drupal8 REST-api for taxonomy terms do not work

Tags: json, rest, api, drupal-8, http-status-code-406

I am writing an Angular2 web app with Drupal8 in the backend. I need to convert taxonomy id's to their respective labels, for that I want to use the API endpoint "/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}". I have enabled the correct REST-API and given access to all roles, however when I try to access that end-point with an ID and ?_format=json, I get the message '{"message":"Not acceptable format: json"}'. If I remove the ?format=json, however, it gives me the results I want in HTML.

This error message is found in the file /core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/AcceptNegotiation406.php and is preceded by the following comment:

```
   // If this is a render array then we assume that the router went with the
    // generic controller and not one with a format. If the format requested is
    // not HTML though we can also assume that the requested format is invalid
    // so we provide a 406 response.
```

Can anyone help me with this? Alternatively, I will have to scrape the taxonomy label from the HTML-result.

Comment: Full URL of API request is "http://bfo.no.drupal.rasmus:7070/taxonomy/term/9?_format=json", but is not available outside of our network.

Answer (score 2):

In `Structure > Views`, disable the "Taxonomy term" view.

This view overrides the `/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}` endpoint created by *RESTful Web Services* module. It won't accept JSON-format requests unless you add a "REST Export" display yourself.